# Why is the output "BEDC" and not "ABCD"? Why was "A" completely ignored?

Tags: java, inheritance

I've read the code in order, and I am still facing trouble in how "A" was not printed.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Circle9();
    }
}
class GeometricObject {
    GeometricObject() {
        System.out.print("A");
    }
    public GeometricObject(String color, boolean filled) {
        System.out.print("B");
    }
}
class Circle9 extends GeometricObject {
    public Circle9() {
        this(1.0);
        System.out.print("C");
    }
    public Circle9(double radius) {
        this(radius, "white", false);
        System.out.print("D");
    }
    public Circle9(double radius, String color, boolean filled) {
        super(color, filled);
        System.out.print("E");
    }
}
```

I was thinking Java is prioritizing methods that link to the super class, but I am not sure if that is the case.

Comment: To achieve the behavior you expected you shouldto call super() on the constructor with no arguments. The  same you did on the contructor with 3 arguments.

Comment: This looks pretty straight forward because you're explicitly calling this and super. You enter the no-arg constructor, which calls the double constructor, which calls the three arg constructor, which calls the two arg super constructor. Which prints B. Then you finish the 3arg constructor and prints E, then you finish the 2 arg constructor and print D then you print C.

Comment: Please read a primer, for example https://www.baeldung.com/java-constructor-specification

Comment: @marcellorvalle you cannot call `super(...)` if calling `this(...)` (and apparently the intention is to create a circle with radius 1.0 if none is given)

Comment: Why would A be printed?

Answer (score 2):

The rule is that every class in the hierarchy **must** run at least 1 constructor. It may run more, but only if you use `this()`.

In other words, **all** constructors **must** start with either a `super()` call or a `this()` call. If you fail to do this, java will inject `super();` for you. If that isn't legal (because the parent class doesn't have a visible-to-the-subclass no-args constructor) then your constructor will not compile until you add an explicit `this()` or `super()` to it on the first line<sup>1</sup>

Thus, from the top down:

- You call the no-arg constructor of `Circle9` ➔ `Circle9()`.
- This calls `this(1.0)` ➔ `Circle9(double)`.
- This calls `this(r, "w", false)` ➔ `Circle9(double, String, boolean)`.
- This calls `super(c, f)` ➔ `GeometricObject(String, boolean)`
- This calls `super()` (implicitly) ➔ `java.lang.Object`'s `()` constructor.
- `java.lang.Object`'s no-arg constructor is the only one that can manage to not call `this` or `super` - and does absolutely nothing, and returns.
- `GeometricObject(color, filled)` returns from its `super` and prints `B`.
- `Circle9(rad, col, fil)` returns from its `super` and prints `E`.
- `Circle9(rad)` returns from its `this(r, c, f)` and prints `D`.
- `Circle9()` returns from its `this(r)` and prints `C`.

I'm not sure why you expected `A` to print.

Remember that each constructor **always** starts with exactly one `this` or `super` call. No more, no less. If it doesn't appear to have such a statement, then it does - it has `super();` - you just don't see it, because `javac` acts like that's there.

1. There is some debate on the OpenJDK developer mailing lists to ease restrictions on this. It's also purely a `javac` (Java-the-lang) rule; the runtime doesn't care. You can hack your way into constructors that don't call parent constructors by modifying bytecode and this won't trigger the verifier as far as I recall. In fact, `java.lang.Object` is one such class (its constructor, naturally, doesn't invoke super; it has no superclass either, which you also can't do with `javac`, as `javac` will add `extends Object` if you don't write an `extends` yourself.